# Is there a simple octave/matlab toolkit for user interface creation with generic layout?

Tags: matlab, octave

#### State of the art

Octave allows the creation of user interfaces. While matlab provides with `GUIDE` a complex tool for graphical design and editing of user interfaces octave has no such tool. Instead you have to place ui elements manually by specifying numeric coordinates in the ui window coordinate system.

On the other hand there are many layout engines for user interfaces in the field like in *qt* or even *x-windows* and in *android* or in web browsers for *html*. So the problem has been solved many times yet.

#### Requested solution

I am looking for a solution that would allow the generic placement of user interface components for example in a table or grid layout.

I imagine using a layout engine like for html tables. You define a table where you place the ui elements one per cell. For some flexibility you can create combined cells spanning multiple columns or rows.

Each cell should be automatically sized to at least fit the element inside and to equally distribute the elements. Layout options allow positioning ui elements within a cell.

Of course it should be possible to create nested structures by placing a new table inside a table cell.

#### Pseudo code

Here comes some pseudo code how the definition of an ui could look like.

```
ui = cell(2,2);
addUIElement(ui, 1,1, uicontrol("style", "text", "string", "This is text"));
addUIElement(ui, 1,2, uicontrol("style", "text", "string", "This is another text"));
addUIElement(ui, 2,1, uicontrol ("style", "pushbutton", "string", "Push me");
addUIElement(ui, 2,2, uicontrol ("style", "pushbutton", "string", "Push me too");
% Create and draw the user interface
gui = CreatGui(ui);
```

#### Notes

- An object oriented implementation may be more suitable than a functional interface
- Additional options to the `addUIElement` function may control placement in cells and other layout options.

#### Question

Are there any suggestions for an implementation in octave using existing code?

Comment: The coordinates can be 'normalised' (i.e. percentage units). You could simply define the coordinates of your desired grid as a cell array, and plug those directly into the `position` argument of your `uicontrol` function. There really isn't more need for a more elaborate "gridding" interface.

Comment: This reads (with the many requirements) like an assignment at school/college. If you consider Tasos' comment it shouldn't be to hard to implement this. Consider pushing it to github/bitbucket/wahtever and add a link here if finished

Comment: @Tasos: Normalized units are nice as long as you are not going to change your design. A design change of user interface may happen by designers decission or - what is even more interesting - in generic user interfaces. Example: Make a group of buttons for a number of options adapting to available options. In any case you have to correct all coordinates in your design. This could be automated with a layout engine. Maybe I have to explain this in more detail in the questions.

Comment: @Andy: Thank you for this hint. Maybe my question is a bit too "big" for this platform. In deed it could be a nice college project. But I know that there are solutions for this type of layout engines available for example in X-Windows or qt. My hope was to find a hint to an octave adaptable solution here. I should add this to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of a 'package' for this, but here's a short example simulating a simple 'layout' approach.
<sub>(usual sanity checks omitted for brevity).</sub>

```
function guitesto
  ui      = cell(2,2);
  layout  = defineLayout (size (ui));  

  ui{1,1} = uicontrol ("style", "text", "string", "This is text");
  ui{1,2} = uicontrol ("style", "text", "string", "This is another text");
  ui{2,1} = uicontrol ("style", "pushbutton", "string", "Push me");
  ui{2,2} = uicontrol ("style", "pushbutton", "string", "Push me too");

  applyLayout (ui, layout)
end

function Out = defineLayout (Gridsize)
  VGridCoords = linspace (0, 1, Gridsize(1) + 1);
  HGridCoords = linspace (0, 1, Gridsize(2) + 1);
  Out = cell();
  for Row = 1 : Gridsize(1), for Col = 1 : Gridsize(2)
    Out{Row, Col} = [HGridCoords(Col), ...
                     1 - VGridCoords(Row+1), ...
                     HGridCoords(Col+1) - HGridCoords(Col), ...
                     VGridCoords(Row+1) - VGridCoords(Row)];
  end, end
end

function applyLayout (ui, layout)
  for Row = 1 : size (ui, 1), for Col = 1: size (ui, 2)
    set (ui{Row, Col}, 'units'   , 'normalized', ...
                       'position', layout{Row, Col});
  end, end
end
```

[image]

It is not complete, I leave the 'subgrids' problem up to you, but it shouldn't be too difficult to implement. Having said that, there is no "abstract box" functionality on matlab / octave (there's hggroups, but that's something different, I'm not sure that it can be used to house uicontrols), so subgrids
would have to be implemented at the coordinate level.

---

<sup>I feel obliged to nitpick at the question, however. Firstly, GUIDE is mentioned, but I feel it's irrelevant here. Other than allowing you to place things visually by means of a visual grid, this is not a layout manager. At least not in the sense that you imply.</sup>

<sup>Secondly, there's no such things as THE layout manager. Java has about a billion of different layout managers to choose from (from Flow to Gridded to Boxed to whatever, including an 'Absolute' which is basically like octave). Html uses a particular 'flow' approach because that's suited to reflowing text.</sup>

<sup>So a layout manager is simply a set of arbitrary rules, dealing with converting relative to absolute positioning, and possibly dealing with resizing. Octave already has some of those built in, e.g. choosing between pixel vs normalised units, and resize-callback functionality built into each graphics object. I find that one can do what you want very simply through the 'normalized' units system, and there's no need for complicated layout managers like Java ... but if you like 'grids', then translating the former to the latter should be relatively easy as I've shown above.</sup>